# monacaでcordova-plugin-facebook4を利用したい

Tags: android, monaca, facebook

monacaにてphonegap-facebook-pluginを利用してfacebook連携を実装していたのですが、アプリの招待機能も必要となり、appInviteを利用できるcordova-plugin-facebook4に置き換えを試みました。
結果、iosでのビルドは難なく通るのですが、andoroidでビルドが通らなくなってしまいました。

試しにこのプラグインを外すとビルドが通ります。

Cordovaバージョン：
CLIバージョン:5.2.0
iosプラットフォーム:3.9.1
Androidプラットフォーム:4.1.1

以下エラー分抜粋

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project &apos;android&apos;.

&gt; Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration &apos;:_debugCompile&apos;.
   &gt; Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified &gt; com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1
   &gt; Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.2.1/support-v4-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified &gt; com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0
   &gt; Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.2.1/cardview-v7-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified &gt; com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0
   &gt; Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/23.2.1/customtabs-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified &gt; com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0
```

phonegap-facebook-pluginにあったgradleファイルなどが見当たらないのですが、これが原因でしょうか。
知恵を拝借いただけるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 1):

かなり時間がたっていますが、このプラグインは、androidSDKのバージョンが25の環境で実行可能です。しかし、monacaが23までしか対応していないため、利用できません。
phonegap-facebook-pluginも、fb側のアップデートで利用できなくなりましたし、monacaでfb系のプラグインを使うのは諦めて他の環境で開発を進めた方が良いですね。残念・・・